# What time is does the daily Google Photos API Quota Reset?

Tags: google-photos, google-photos-api

I currently have a usage quota of 4,000,000 requests per day via the Google Photo Library API. We're doing a large promotion of our product which has now blown through the quota.

I'm now receiving an error code 429.  Does anyone know what time of day the quota resets?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [docs](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/api-limits-quotas), it will reset in the next day, after midnight.

You can also [request additional quota limit](https://developers.google.com/photos/partner-program/overview)

Comment: What time zone?

Comment: Pacific Standard Time

Answer (score 0):

Daily quotas are replenished daily at midnight Pacific time. Per-minute quotas are refreshed every 60 seconds. refer to [this document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/quotas#:%7E:text=Daily%20quotas%20are%20replenished%20daily%20at%20midnight%20Pacific%20time.)